# Dynamic Lambda expressions for filter and sorting using children using c#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, linq-expressions, ef-core-2.0

hello i follow the guide in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries to create filter and sorting in my relation class, i need to filter and sort using the children column "Channel"

this is my base class

```
public class MeterTransaction : EviModelBase
{        
    public int TariffDuration { get; set; }
    public decimal? TariffPackageKwh { get; set; }
    public decimal? TariffPackagePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? TariffRatePerKwh { get; set; }
    public decimal? TariffRateMinFee { get; set; }

    // Meter CreditBalance after transaction
    public decimal CreditBalance { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CreditExpiration { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public Meter Meter { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the Meter Class

```
public class Meter : EviModelBase
{
    public MeterVendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
```

}

this is the code to filter and sort the data :

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByNew<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, SortModel sortModel)
            {
                    ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

                    // Construct the nested properties
                    string[] nestedProps = sortModel.ColId.Split('.');
                    Expression mbr = p;
                    for (int i = 0; i < nestedProps.Length; i++)
                            mbr = Expression.PropertyOrField(mbr, nestedProps[i]);

                    LambdaExpression pred = Expression.Lambda(
                            Expression.Equal(
                                    mbr,
                                    Expression.Constant("EVI0000101")
                                    ),
                                    p
                    );

                    var method = string.Equals(sortModel.Sort, "desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?
                            "OrderByDescending" :
                            "OrderBy";
                    var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "where", new Type[] { source.ElementType }, source.Expression, pred);
                    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(mbr, p);

                    MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                            typeof(Queryable),
                            method,
                            new Type[] { source.ElementType},
                            whereCallExpression,
                            Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
                    // ***** End OrderBy *****

                    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByCallExpression);
            }
    }
```

Actually the "whereCallExpression" is working fined and filtering the data that i want without error, but the sorting logic give an error "no generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments."

how can i achieve this ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that in contrast with `Where`, the `OrderBy` method has 2 generic type arguments (`TSource` and `TKey`). Hence you need to provide them both when generating a call:

```
var orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    method,
    new Type[] { source.ElementType, orderByExpression.Body.Type }, // <--
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
```

Comment: thx this solve my problem, btw is there anyway to change the filter expressions from "==" into "like" or "contains "

Comment: Sure, instead of `Expression.Equal` you could use `Expression.Call(mbr, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant("EVI0000101"))`

Comment: once again thx @Ivan Stoev, is there any usefull documentation about this ? it can help me alot

Comment: Not that I know. All my experience is coming from self learning and experimenting. Explore the `Expression` class static methods. Or in most of the cases, it's easier to create sample compile time expression (e.g. `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = x => x.Bar.Contains("Baz");` and examine the content inside the debugger. Then find the appropriate static methods to build it dynamically :)